# ASP.NET MVC Multi site - where to store site configuration data

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC multi site application (can host multiple sites from the same application instance / multi-tenant application).

I've previously done this in a web forms application and loaded up the appropriate site configuration data (by inspecting the url) on the page_load event of a custom base page.

With ASP.NET MVC would I be best to do the same in Application_BeginRequest? I can then add the configuration object to HttpContext.Current.Items.

Comment: What do you mean by multi-site?  Like many clients on one machine?  Many domains, one server?

Comment: I think he means a multi-tenant application.

Comment: I've updated my question - realize I was a bit vague. Basically this is like the multi store feature in Magento Commerce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm doing something similar with the current system I'm working on.

I'm determining the site by the url the user accesses the application as follows:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        var host = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host;
        Site = _siteService.GetSiteByHost(host);

        base.Initialize(requestContext);
    }       
}
```

Every `Controller` then extends `BaseController`, so the `Site` object is available to every `Controller`. If you have any more specific questions, ask and I'll let you know what we did.

**update**

What you see above is `_siteService.GetSiteByHost(host)`. `SiteService` has a caching layer between it and the Repository, which takes care of all the cache related stuff. it is defined as:

```
public Site GetSiteByHost(string host)
{
    string rawKey = GetCacheKey(string.Format("GetSiteByHost by host{0}", host));

    var site = (Site)_cachingService.GetCacheItem(rawKey);

    if (site == null)
    {
        site = _siteRepository.GetSiteByHost(host);
        AddCacheItem(rawKey, site);
    }

    return site;
}
```

We try not to use the `Session` unless we're dealing with simple data types, like an integer. I wouldn't store a `Site` object in the Session, but I would store an integer that represents the `SiteId` in the session. Then the next time the user accesses the application, I can get the `Site` object that's associated with the current user from the cache by Id. In the case above though that's not necessary.

Comment: Dave, one question - I assume that when you caching items or using the session object, you are prefixing your keys with the site identifier?

Comment: Would also like to share this link as it's kind of related - discussing new .NET 4 System.Runtime.Cache and example of rolling own cache provider - http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Glucose/Hanselminutes-on-9-ASPNET-4-and-the-new-ObjectCache-with-Stefan/

Comment: No problem man, but if either of these answers (or any others on StackOverflow) are correct, make sure to mark it as such!! That's what gives this site its value

Comment: @DaveDev - I've marked yours as the answer as it was more specific to my question. The link by @Lucas was also very useful.

Answer (score 2):

[This blogger](http://weblogs.asp.net/zowens/archive/tags/Multi-tenancy/default.aspx) has what looks to be a decent series of articles about multi-tenancy in asp.net-mvc

What you mention sounds like a workable way of doing what you want, though it may not be the idiomatic solution.

Comment: Thanks for the link - looks like it covers just what I need.

Comment: No problem...saved it for myself as well :)